# Async only works when stepping through debugger

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf, asynchronous

I've been getting very strange behavior from my code.

Basically, my code is using an Input/Output stream to download a .pdf file from the internet, saving it to internal storage (using an AsyncTask) and then outputting it using an outside "showPdf" library.

The strangest thing is that it only works on two conditions:

1. I run the code twice (run or debug without any break points). The first run logs ***File is empty*** when showPdf() is called, but the second run through runs perfectly fine when showPdf() is called on its own.
2. I debug the code and step through the program

As a  preface, I'm new to java and android studio, so my guess may not be right at all, but I'm guessing since the InputStream is being done "asynchronously", showPdf() may be called before the byte[] array is written into memory. If this is the case, what could I do to delay Async long enough to work?

```
public class pdfView extends AppCompatActivity {
    PDFView pdfView; //pdfView object
    String URL;
    String fileName;
    File directory; //path of created File
    // Container for all parameters of DownloadAsync
    private static class AsyncParameters {
        String URL;
        File directory;
        AsyncParameters(String URL, File directory) {
            this.URL = URL;
            this.directory = directory;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_view);

        //Grab the extras from the intent call
        Intent intent = getIntent(); //whatever calls this activity, gather the intent
        URL = intent.getStringExtra("File URL"); // in this case, get the file name of the "extra" passed through
        fileName = intent.getStringExtra("File Name");

        //Grab the internal storage directory and create a folder if it doesn't exist
        File intDirectory = getFilesDir();
        File folder = new File(intDirectory, "pdf");
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = folder.exists();

        //See if the file exists
        if (!isDirectoryCreated) {
            isDirectoryCreated= folder.mkdir();
        }
        if(isDirectoryCreated) {
            directory = new File(folder, fileName);
            try {
                directory.createNewFile();
                if (directory.canWrite())
                    Log.d("hngggggggggggggg", "onCreate: ");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            //See if file already exists
            boolean empty = directory.length() == 0;
            if (empty){
                /**Call class to create parameter container**/
                AsyncParameters param = new AsyncParameters(URL, directory);
                DownloadAsync Downloader = new DownloadAsync();
                Downloader.execute(param);
                showPdf();
            }
            else
                showPdf();
        }

    }
    public void showPdf()
    {
        pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromFile(directory).load();
    }

    /**Class for asynchronous tasks**/
    public class DownloadAsync extends AsyncTask<AsyncParameters, Void, Void> {

        // Container for all parameters of DownloadAsync
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(pdfView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Database...");
            String message= "Downloading Files";

            SpannableString ss2 =  new SpannableString(message);
            ss2.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, ss2.length(), 0);
            ss2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, ss2.length(), 0);

            pDialog.setMessage(ss2);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(AsyncParameters... params) {
            Log.d("WE ARE IN DOBACKGROUND", "doInBackground: ");
            String fileURL = params[0].URL;
            File directory = params[0].directory;
            try {

                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
                java.net.URL u = new URL(fileURL);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                c.connect();
                InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                f.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            onPostExecute();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute() {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what asynchronous means. Your aynctask does not necessarily finish before the rest of your function

Comment: @njzk2 I am well aware of that. I meant more so that the async task was working in tandem with my main thread. But thank you for the input regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have answered your own question. Since the download is asyncTask running on a different thread, there is no wait for the asyncTask to complete before `showPdf()` is called. You can call `showPdf()` from `onPostExecute()` which is called after the background task completes. Your code should look like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ........
    ........

    AsyncParameters param = new AsyncParameters(URL, directory);
    DownloadAsync Downloader = new DownloadAsync();
    Downloader.execute(param);

    .......
    .......
}

public class DownloadAsync extends AsyncTask<AsyncParameters, Void, Void> {
    .......

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        showPdf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually figured it out after I slept on it. Sleep deprivation coding is something else